# SQL Server and Excel

Tags: excel, sql-server-2014

I want to link an excel file to SQL Server 2014 whereby I can edit the file and the data gets updated on the server automatically.
Similar to what happens when you link sql server to Access whereas you can edit the data and the changes take effect in the server.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of the box solution for this. You can do this either of two ways:

1. Write a C# code which has a file watcher attached to the Excel file which uploads the Excel file using SSIS job to the database.
2. Create a scheduled SSIS job which imports the Excel file periodically.

Understanding the purpose would allow for greater elaboration.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the type of data you wish to edit.

For master data, if you have the Enterprise or Business Intelligence edition of SQL Server and Master Data Services set up, there is a plug-in for Excel:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231024(v=sql.120).aspx

For transactional data, I would strongly advise against using Excel as a front-end and would recommend you to consider alternatives.

However, if you are compelled to go down this route, you can achieve this using VBA scripting and linking via a DAL (Data Access Layer) such as ADO.NET.  Be aware that giving such power to your users could open up your system to sql injection attacks - only proceed so if you trust the users 100%.  Another thing to take into consideration is validation checks - validation checks should be applied to every cell where data can be entered.  More information can be found here:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/316934